# Programmatic back button in web view (WebKit)

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, webkit

I've added a back button to my webView, but I'm having trouble setting it up to actually go back -

I have this function:

```
func goBack() {
    if webView.canGoBack {
        webView.goBack()
    }
}
```

And in `didSelectRowAt IndexPath` I have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    webView.load(URLRequest(url: self.urls[indexPath.row]))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    view = webView

    // Title/Back button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
}
```

But tapping on the back button does nothing - I'm not sure what steps I'm missing to make this work. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score 0):

You have set target as `webView`, which should be `self`.

Try this and see:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
```

> Note: You have assigned action to navigation item in table row
>   selection (`didSelectRowAt`), so You need to select any row first and
>   then this will work. This button won't work, if you directly tap/click
>   on button without selecting any row. To check it's functionality, move your code to `viewDidLoad`

I've tried following code and it's working

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.goBack))
 }

 func goBack() {
     print("goBack...")
 }
```

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately - button still does nothing.

Comment: I see you set up the button in `viewDidLoad` - I have it only in `didSelectRow`, because I only want the back button to appear if the user is currently in webView - if they're in the tableview, there should be no button.

Comment: Even if I move the code to viewDidLoad, the button does nothing. I've already set the target to "self".

Comment: I'm using a navigation controller, not sure if that would make a difference. I have a table view embedded in the navigation controller, and the user can tap on the cells to load a news story. I want a back button to appear in the nav bar when the web view comes up.

Comment: Just try this code in new/fresh view controller and see